# Understanding request object in servlet-api. Is it a singleton?

Tags: java, servlets

I read the servlet-3.0 specification and have got one question about the `ServletRequest` object. Currenctly I have a filter chain

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter{

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         //do filter
    }
}
```

after doing filters the `javax.servlet.Servlet`'s

```
public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException;
```

comes into play. Is it reliable that both in the filter's method and the `service` method operate on the same object reference? The servlet specification said this:

> Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s 
>   service  method, or  within the scope of a filter ’s  doFilter 
>   method, unless the asynchronous processing  is enabled for the
>   component and the startA sync method is invoked on the request  object

But it;s not obvious to me that the `ServletRequest` object is a singleton per one request handling.

***Upd***: To be more specific, I need to return the `HttpSession` instance within `Filter`'s `doFilter` method and `Servlet`'s `do_HttpMethod_` method. Is it always the same? I mean `httpServletRequest.getSession()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServletRequest` is an interface and the same is used in `doFilter` method as well as `service` method. So both are going to return the same session object (if you call getSession()).

Servlet as well as Filter uses same interface so it's going to behave same way. I am not sure why you are curious to know if it's singleton ? May be you can check servlet specification to know more about it.

Comment: Thanks much, but is it strictly specified in the serlvet-api docs?

Comment: AFAIK it's not specified in spec.

Answer (score 1):

A container uses a single request object for a given request. However any filter can wrapper the request object so your filter or servlet may be getting a wrapper depending on what other filters do. Usually as an app developer you would know if this is the case. If no wrappers are used the filter and servlets get the same request object.

For info on request wrappers see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html

So when you call getSession() you may get the container implementation of the method or that provided by a wrapper. However note that an HttpServletRequestWrapper object provides a getRequest() method which returns the request object it wraps so you can recurse through wrappers until you get the original and then call it. Lots of examples how to do this on the web.